# Ember: Call an action from a button in a nested div

Tags: ember.js, action

So I have an Ember application that uses bootstrap. I got that working fine it seems, but I'm having issues getting a button from within a dropdown menu to trigger an action. I can have a button outside of that dropdown call the same action, and it works fine.

**Controller:**

```
actions: {
clearWords: function(){
       console.log("clear it!!");
  }
}
```

**HBS:**

```
<li>
   <div class="dropdown"> ...
      <button type="button" {{action "clearWords"}}>Clear</button>
   ...
   </div> 
</li>
<li>
  <button type="button" {{action "clearWords"}}>Clear</button>
  <!-- ^^ this one works -->
</li>
```

I've tried adding target to the action bit, but that never works either.

```
{{action "clearWords" target="controller.controllerName"}}
```

Any suggestions to get me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

*PS: If you happen to be kind enough post sample code from JSBin, could you use JSFiddle instead? I can't see JSBin behind my proxy here :(*

Comment: The Bootstrap dropdown uses some Javascript, could there be some interference there? Does Bootstrap cancel events/event bubbling in that dropdown?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sara_acid/ykmamspf/) . Can you show more code. Certain third party js does cancel event bubbling which causes ember actions not to be triggered. but i dont think bootstrap dropdown does anything like that.

Comment: Thanks guys, turns out there was a `stopPropagation()` called in further up in the controller that was preventing the action from bubbling up. We were using that to keep the dropdown menu open when clicked inside. Thanks to your suggestions, I was able to narrow that down.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, turns out there was a `stopPropagation()` called further up in the controller that kept the action from bubbling up. We were using this to keep the dropdown menu open through various clicks.

Hopefully this will help someone else troubleshoot their code. I didn't think bootstrap would be blocking the actions, but this certainly explains it.